# Solving one equation, then inputting the values into another for NonlinearModelFit

Tags: equation-solving, fitting, polynomials, modeling

Considering the equation

```
a*x^3 + a*x^2 + x + b == 0
```

I'm looking to find the best value for `a` and `x` from the above polynomial (with `b` known) for which the second function using the same `a` and `x`

```
(65 + 103*a*x^2)/(1 + a*x^2)
```

gives me the closest `NonlinearModelFit` for an already determined set of (x,y) coordinates.

Comment: If you fit your data to the model you get an expression for a. If you use that in the first equation you can than `Solve` or `NSolve` that for x. The phrasing of your question seems rather peculiar to me. If you have determined a using the fit you cannot use the first equation to determine a again as you seem to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{0, 64.88916615388398`}, {1, 83.24718374138278`}, {2,
 93.75766523300271`}, {3, 99.74735460092744`}, {4, 
101.22704834518477`}, {5, 105.38706473218782`}, {6, 
100.10310736034148`}, {7, 104.83229572643938`}, {8, 
103.76491949073773`}, {9, 105.68123555532274`}, {10, 
99.70060366431277`}};

sol =  NonlinearModelFit[data, (65 + 103*a*x^2)/(1 + a*x^2), {a}, x]["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {a -> 0.951042699}

```
Solve[a*x^3 + a*x^2 + x + b == 0 /. sol /. b -> 1, x]
```

> {{x -> -1.}, {x -> 0. - 1.02541577 I}, {x -> 
>      0. + 1.02541577 I}}